# Adding properties to django model

Tags: django, wiki

So I am building a Django based wiki-type app. I hacked it together from bits of code and now I am trying to add all the necessary functionality for our specific needs.

However, what I want to do is to be able to add values from a couple of drop down menus. One is for the Country, and the other is the category. So the end result is something that ends up like -Afghanistan->Politics->Afghan Constitution.

Currently the model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.

class PublishedArticlesManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(PublishedArticlesManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_published=True)

class Article(models.Model):
"""Represents a wiki article"""

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
text = models.TextField(help_text="Formatted using ReST")
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Publish?")
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
objects = models.Manager()
published = PublishedArticlesManager()
```

Should I be adding those properties to this model?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

- Create a separate class for categories and country.
- Use foreign keys to establish the relationships between categories, countries, and articles.
- You can create a recursive relationship so that each category can have a parent 
  (i.e. `parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')`)

Answer (score 0):

`country` is an attribute with a static set of choices. As such, I'd use a static list of countries (in fact, I have one [here](http://pastebin.com/5QdFZH6J) for you, extracted form pycountry 0.14.8). As the choices are freely available in your Django application, this saves database hits. As long as an article is attributed to a single country, I would include it as a field in the `Article` model (and probably index it as well). Even if you sometimes need multiple countries, a slight alteration of a [`CommaSeparatedIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) could provide for an easy solution.

Categories are more dynamic in nature, and often more categories are added or some of them are changed or removed. For this a separate model is a good idea. As RohitJ suggested, you can have a model with a recursive relation to itself to allow parent categories. Many existing apps also provide category models that easily be incorporated in your project, e.g. [django-categories](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-categories/) which I use in my current project.